Can anything in Rust be turned into or from bytes?
I am creating a protocol simulation and research tool made with Rust as a library for Python through maturin and Pyo3. I´m relying on different crates that implement protocols in a secure way, but I run into the same problem every time I use a structs from a crate, the problem being that when I try to turn the data from a variable into bytes or from it to make use those types in Python, I run into this problem:

no method named to_bytes found for struct sidh::sidh::SIDHSecretKeyBob in the current scope
method not found in SIDHSecretKeyBob

#[pyfunction]
pub fn sidh_keygen(py: Python) -> PyResult<(Py<PyBytes>, Py<PyBytes>, Py<PyBytes>, Py<PyBytes>)> {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();

    // Generate key pairs for Alice and Bob
    let (alice_public, alice_secret) = generate_alice_keypair(&mut rng);
    let (bob_public, bob_secret) = generate_bob_keypair(&mut rng);

    // Convert keys to bytes for Python compatibility
    let alice_pub_bytes = PyBytes::new_bound(py, &alice_public.to_bytes());
    let bob_pub_bytes = PyBytes::new_bound(py, &bob_public.to_bytes());
    let alice_sec_bytes = PyBytes::new_bound(py, &alice_secret.to_bytes()); // Serializing Alice's secret
    let bob_sec_bytes = PyBytes::new_bound(py, &bob_secret.to_bytes());     // Serializing Bob's secret

    // Returning both public keys and secret keys for encapsulation/decapsulation
    Ok((alice_pub_bytes.into(), alice_sec_bytes.into(), bob_pub_bytes.into(), bob_sec_bytes.into()))
}

I´m not used to Rust yet but I thought there should be an easy way to do the to_bytes or from_bytes in "anything" so it can be used right? Maybe there is a better approach to working with data types through Python with maturin and Pyo3.

There isn't a universal to_bytes implementation, because there are a lot of types where serializing them in a safe and robust way requires more information than is available just through the type system. The most common practice in Rust is for types that are serializable to implement the interfaces in the serde crate, and then to use a serialization implementation like bincode to convert them to bytes. Many crates/libraries have optional serde feature flags that you can enable to make their types serializable. However, it looks like the one you're using does not, so you're out luck.

Although in your case, it looks like the SIDHSecretKeyBob struct's members are all pub, so you can just access .scalar and have the bytes as a byte array that way, so you don't need any to_bytes method or other serialization. You might just need to convert between a byte array and a byte vector or something like that.

Thank you very much for the in depth answer, I will try that then as it sounds "doable", although it is a shame there is no .serialize or something like that that just works for any case. At least what feels good is knowing I wasn´t just not seeing an obvious way to do it.

To give an example of why there is no built-in way to do this for any type, any struct containing a String contains three pieces of info: a pointer, a length, and a capacity. The actual characters are not stored inline in the String; they are allocated on the heap. So if you just take the raw contents of the String value as bytes and ship them around, you're missing the actual characters of the string. Worse, if you "thaw" those bytes back into a String without properly "forgetting" the original String, you will cause use-after-free or double-free bugs.

And, even if you properly handle the lifetime of the String, the bytes are only useful in the address space of the program in which they were created. Shipping them over a network or even to a different process on the same system will be pointless.
